What laws apply to the possession of pocket knives by minors in California?
What, if any, California laws regarding the possession of pocket knives apply specifically to minors?

There might be local city or county ordinances, but there is nothing in the Californian penal code regarding the possession of pocket knives that apply specifically to minors.
These are only 3 laws I've found and they all refer to "Any knife with a blade length in excess of four inches, the blade of which is fixed or is capable of being fixed in an unguarded position by the use of one or two hands." But don't specifically refer to possession by minors.

171.b (a) Any person who brings or possesses within any state or local public building or at any meeting required to be open to the public pursuant to Chapter 9 (commencing with Section 54950) of Part 1 of Division 2 of Title 5 of, or Article 9 (commencing with Section 11120) of Chapter 1 of Part 1 of Division 3 of Title 2 of, the Government Code, any of the following is guilty of a public offense punishable by imprisonment in a county jail for not more than one year, or in the state prison:


171c.(2) Any person who brings or possesses, within the State Capitol, any legislative office, any hearing room in which any committee of the Senate or Assembly is conducting a hearing, the Legislative Office Building at 1020 N Street in the City of Sacramento, the state office building at 1021 O Street in the City of Sacramento, or upon the grounds of the State Capitol, which is bounded by 10th, L, 15th, and N Streets in the City of Sacramento, any of the following, is guilty of a misdemeanor punishable by imprisonment in a county jail for a period not to exceed one year, or by a fine not exceeding one thousand dollars ($1,000), or by both that fine and imprisonment, if the area is posted with a statement providing reasonable notice that prosecution may result from possession of any of these items:


171.5 (c) It is unlawful for any person to knowingly possess, within any sterile area of an airport or a passenger vessel terminal, any of the following items:

Extracted frm california penal code
And, it also depends on what you mean by minor


All persons are capable of committing crimes except those belonging to the following classes:

One—Children under the age of 14, in the absence of clear proof that at the time of committing the act charged against them, they knew its wrongfulness.

